# How to dismiss keyboard when using reat-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

What's the best way to dismiss a keyboard when I have a full-screen `MapView` (react-native-maps) which has a `TextInput` overlaid near the top of the screen.

If the user begins entering something in the keyboard but then drags on the `MapView` i want the keyboard to be dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

In your MapView

add this

```
<MapView>
  onPress = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss();}}
  onRegionChange = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss();}}
</MapView>
```

The onPress will close the keyboard when you press the map
the OnRegionChange will close the keyboard when you move the map

remember to import Keyboard from react-native like this

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is call a function on drag of mapView, like :

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

onNavigateToMaps = () => {

Keyboard.dismiss();
navigate('Maps');
}
```

hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```js
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

Keyboard.dismiss()// Hide keyboard
```

[Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard)